# Render certain passes only WITHOUT the combined

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, render-passes

I wish to de-noise my render using the compositor but I found half-way that I have no environment or emission layer selected. As rendering takes time, I wish to render **only that two** in order to be able to combine the passes again later on after I adjusted the noise of my indirect passes. 
Question is, how to render only some given passes **without** rendering the combined pass?

**EDIT**

Or does it work if I just remove the tick from the `combined` option?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get the result you want by unchecking "Combined" and just using **Z** and **Emit**. However! I **strongly** recommend that you **first** back up your existing render (and any other render layers) as 16-bit TIF images or EXRs incase of: Blender crashing during re-render, overwriting existing renders, etc.

Comment: I did save it of course. I tried the other one meself, but didn't work out unfortunately :/ Luckily though I didn't need it. The layers could be replicated easily by re-rendering everything with a less expensive shader setup.